# Using router inside Symfony Form class

Tags: php, symfony

Here's what i'm trying to achieve. I'm using the `SymfonyContrib\Bundle\LinkButtonBundle\LinkButtonBundle` to add a simple back/cancel link to my form right beside the submit button. Problem is that I don't know how to get to my router so that I can use the generate method to generate route url's. Anyone have an idea how to either inject the router into my form or pass the URL from my controller where the form is created with `$this->createform('my_form_foo')`

```
<?php

namespace My\Form;

use \Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use \Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class Foo extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(
                'username',
                null,
                [
                    'label' => 'Username',
                    'attr' => [
                        'placeholder' => 'User name',
                    ],
                    'required' => true
                ]
            )
            ->add('actions', 'form_actions', [
                'buttons' => [
                    'save' => [
                        'type' => 'submit'
                    ],
                    'cancel' => [
                        'type' => 'button',
                        'options' => [
                            'url' => '/', // This needs to be generated from a route
                            'label' => 'Back'
                        ]
                    ],
                ]
            ]);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'my_form_foo';
    }
}
```

Comment: If your form is registered as a service (which seems to be the case, judging by `my_form_foo`), simply use the option `arguments` to pass the router, or use the third argument of `createForm` and access your generated URL from `$options`.

Comment: @Artamiel what option can I use for this because it seems that i can't just add any arbitrary option since it throws "The option ... does not exist" when i just add an 'back_url' option.

Comment: You need to include the option with `null` value **at least** in your default options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific case, it's a better practice to add buttons directly in the view.

(Something like that)

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
  {{ form_widget(form) }}

  <button type="submit" value="Save" />
  <a href="{{ path('name_route') }}" role="button">Back</a>

{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can inject the router into the form class if you register your form as a service in the service container.

See: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to manage all the form actions in the Controller Class. As described [in the doc here](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-3-buttons-support-in-forms), you can add your button for flow-control:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
    ->add('name', 'text')
    ->add('save', 'submit')
    ->add('save_and_add', 'submit')
    ->getForm();
```

And manage the flow in the controller as:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    // ... do something

    // the save_and_add button was clicked
    if ($form->get('save_and_add')->isClicked()) {
        // probably redirect to the add page again
    }

    // redirect to the show page for the just submitted item
}
```

Hope this help